# RequestHeader not getting set on RewriteRule in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-headers

The following RewriteRule in my htaccess file isn't getting the request header set.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&someUser=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)SDM$ http://some.domain.com/SDM/Publish.aspx [E=SOME:%2,R,L]
RequestHeader set Some-User: "%{SOME}e"
```

I don't think the SOME environment variable has anything to do with it because I tried a generic header value as well and it wasn't set either.  I did make sure that mod-headers is installed.  I am looking for the header in my chrome developer tools.  Is it possible that it won't show up there?

Comment: From what I understand, it makes it appear to the content-handler (php or whatever handles aspx) that the request was made with a certain header, while the original request didn't have that header. It doesn't affect headers that are sent back.

Answer (score 2):

**Env variables won't be set while doing external redirect**, you must do internal rewrite for setting env variables like this:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)someUser=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)SDM$ /SDM/Publish.aspx [E=SOME:%2,L]

RequestHeader set Some-User "%{SOME}e"
```